# Browsers trying to download PHP files instead of running them (Linux Mint, Apache2)

Tags: php, linux, apache

I already disabled

```
php_admin_flag engine Off
```

in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php.conf` and still PHP files won't work. I've encountered similar problem with `SWF` files already and the cause was in `mime-types`. So I suspect that current problem may be related. Still, I don't know how to change `mime-type` for `.php`?

Comment: Do you have lines similar to the following in httpd.conf?

    LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

Comment: @RobGudgeon, no. And I only have similar file in /etc/phpmyadmin/lighttpd.conf.

Comment: if you're using Apache, you need to configure it to process .php files as PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it all was because of me trying to run .php files outside `DocumentRoot` directory, which is `/var/www/html` meaning it's protected and I would either run IDE (for development) in root mode or change `DocumentRoot` option.